# swift + global array is null after the task

Tags: arrays, swift, task

This is the code:

```
var loans = [Loan]()
func getLastestLoans()
{
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URLRequest(url: loanUrl),
    completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    if let error = error {
       print(error)
       return
    }
    // Parse JSON data
    if let data = data {
       self.loans = self.parseJSONData(data: data) 
       print(self.loans.count) //Now the value of loans is not null
       OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
       self.tableView.reloadData() })
     }       
  })
  task.resume()
}
```

But after the task ,the loans is null. loans is the global variables, why there is no value in loans after i run the function getLastestLoans.

Comment: It's asynchronous. It will be `nil` until you set it just before reloading the table view. The code you posted is fine. What problem are you having?

Comment: I want to copy the value to loans through self.parseJSONData, and self.loans is not null,but after the task, the loans is null.

Comment: Put a breakpoint after the task and on the line where you print `self.loans`. Note which one is called first. You need to understand the flow of asynchronous calls.

Comment: Thank you, i have solved the problem.